# Having issues with setting up Inbound Email in SP2010

Tags: email, sharepoint-2010

I am having issues with setting up the Inbound Email with SP 2010.  I have enabled the settings in Central Admin for Inbound Email, set up an MX record, added the IP to my Exchange Server, then created a new doc-lib in SP and i am still not seeing the "Incoming e-mail settings" option under communications in the doc-lib setup screen.

Can someone let me know what I may be doing wrong, or missing?

Answer (score 1):

[Technet - Troubleshoot Messaging Integration - Inbound Message Transfer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.insidesharepoint.aspx#id0270031)